# Why can't I upload folders to a Linux EC2 Instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, permissions

I have been uploading my files and folders to my Linux EC2 Instance using SSH for the past month.  Yesterday I updated the Linux version, and since then I cannot upload folders to the Instance, but I can still upload files.  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here's what I'm using to upload folders:

```
$ scp -i /Users/----/Desktop/-----.pem -rp /Users/----/Desktop/Website_Testing_Folder/politics ec2-user@-------:/var/www/html
```

(dashed out personal details)

Here's the error I'm getting:

`scp: /var/www/html/politics: Permission denied`

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: "since then I cannot upload folders to the Instance, but I can still upload folders" - I'm confused...

Comment: @Chris Oops, that was supposed to be "files", sorry!

Comment: I wonder if this is this a local permissions issue? To narrow it down further: Have you tried uploading other folders with the same issue? Or manually ssh-ing in and creating the same folder structure?

Comment: It is possible the Linux upgrade changed the permission of the folder. Just ssh in and fix the folder permissions.

Comment: @Chris If I upload it without the `var/www/html` in the upload command, it works.  However I need it to be in `/var/www/html`, as that is where my website files should be.

Comment: @helloV Thanks a lot for your advice, I did `sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html` and it worked!  Do you want to post it as an answer??

Comment: @JeffArries Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible the Linux upgrade changed the permission of the folder. Just ssh in and fix the folder permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Your user, `ec2-user` does not have permission to write to `/var/www/html`. You can either change the permission of `/var/www/html` using `chmod` or `chown`. Or you can upload the files to your home folder and move it from there.

Comment: Did you steal the answer that @helloV was suggested and I made work? Just wondering.

Comment: I was also getting permission denied error, I used this command and path and it started working,
scp -i /c/wamp/www/mykey.pem file.text ec2-user@10.19.XX.XX:/home/ec2-user/